# NoClassDefFoundError for API level 8

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to make my app compatible for lower API levels. On level 19, everything works fine, but on level 8, this line causes a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityData.class);
```

The Activity I'm trying to open uses android.app.actionBar, so I assume that's the reason the App crashes. But I don't understand why a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. Has anyone an explanation for this?

Also, eclipse doesn't mark the import of android.app.actionBar as a warning or error, although I chose API level 8 as the minimum. Is there an option so eclipse marks the parts of my code that are not compatible with the APIs I chose?

Comment: "But I don't understand why a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown. Has anyone an explanation for this?" -- without seeing the activity in question, that will be difficult to answer. "Also, eclipse doesn't mark the import of android.app.actionBar as a warning or error" -- Lint will not complain about `import` statements. If your `android:minSdkVersion` is set properly, though, it will warn about actual uses of such classes. So, if your `android:minSdkVersion` is less than 11, calls to methods like `getActionBar()` should result in errors, unless you disabled those Lint checks.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about Lint so far, I think this will help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what it means to have different API levels. If the action bar was released on API level 11, then API level 8 does not have the necessary classes and resources to make the action bar work, which is why you're getting the NoClassDefFound error.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, your have already answer the question. Number one thing to understand, Eclipse is not an official Toolkit for Android. For Above mentioned problem, Eclipse can't help us. So, you have to manually defined your api level to 11. if you want to use ActionBar class

Comment: "Number one thing to understand, Eclipse is not an official Toolkit for Android" -- it is most certainly an officially supported IDE for Android.

Comment: Thanks commonsWare for correcting me. By the way, i am fan of your Android's book